# Using ExecuteScalar() in place of ExecuteReader()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am learning Web API and working on a small project (I know this question is not related to Web API, but just to get to the scene). So I have this function called `get_balance(string accountNumber)` which returns the balance:

```
-- Function: deposit.get_balance(character varying)
-- DROP FUNCTION deposit.get_balance(character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deposit.get_balance
     (deposit_account_number_ character varying)
RETURNS money AS
$BODY$
DECLARE _account_number_id bigint;
BEGIN

SELECT account_number_id INTO _account_number_id FROM 
deposit.account_holders WHERE account_number = $1;
RETURN(
SELECT 
SUM(COALESCE(credit,'0')) - SUM(COALESCE(debit, '0'))
FROM deposit.transaction_view
WHERE account_number_id = _account_number_id
);
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION deposit.get_balance(character varying)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Since this is a Web API project, I have an `AccountsController`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("balance")]
public IHttpActionResult GetBalance([FromBody]AccountBalance account)
{
    account = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetBalance(account.AccountNumber);
    return Ok(account);
}
```

The business layer:

```
public static AccountBalance GetBalance(string AccountNumber)
{
    return DatabaseLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetBalance(AccountNumber);
}
```

And the Db layer:

```
public static AccountBalance GetBalance(string AccountNumber)
{
    AccountBalance result = null;

    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;UserId = postgres; " + "Password = pes; Database = pmc; "))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM deposit.get_balance(@AccountNumber);", conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", AccountNumber);

            using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if(dr.HasRows && dr.Read())
                {
                    result = new AccountBalance
                    {
                        AccountNumber = AccountNumber,
                        Balance = dr["get_balance"].ToString(),
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Everything is working as of now and I am getting the expected result

```
{
    "accountNumber": "RD-0000050",
    "balance": "1100"
}
```

What I have learned about `ExecuteScalar` is that it only returns the value from the first column of the first row of your query. And my query returns only one column and I did try using `ExecuteScalar` going through some tuts but alas,  didn't get that working. How do I use `ExecuteScalar` in this scenario? Any detailed link, explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Could you try `SELECT get_balance FROM deposit.get_balance(@AccountNumber)` instead of asterisk?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight hello sir..the query SELECT get_balance FROM deposit.get_balance(@AccountNumber) did worked and thats the only column/result returning.my question is/was how do i use executeScalar in my Db layer GetBalance?i am using executeReader now(it works though), However,function get_balance returns only one column and i want to use executeScalar?help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`:

```
using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT get_balance FROM deposit.get_balance(@AccountNumber);", conn)) {
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", AccountNumber);
    var balanceObj = command.ExecuteScalar();
    string balance = balanceObj != DBNull.Value ? balanceObj.ToString() : "<EMPTY>";
    return new AccountBalance {
        AccountNumber
    ,   Balance = balance
    };
}
return null;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be Balance = balance. The dr var is not defined.

Comment: @OLDMONK: Even if your query returns more than one column, `ExecuteScalar()` will never look at these extra columns. You will always get the first column from the first row, **regardless** of how many rows or columns are returned.

Comment: @Flater this was a comment to an older version of the answer. It is now obsolete.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you sir